# Automatically start an application with a modifed LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: debian, options, rc, ld

I have an application that needs a modified LD_PRELOAD.
I want to start the application using the originally provided rc script, so I can benefit from an automatically updated rc script on an update of the application. I can't modify the original rc script of course, because any change would be lost on the next update.

So, is there maybe some system settings like: If starting application X, use a modified LD_PRELOAD? Or would my best way really be to copy the original rc script, modify it and use the modified rc script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The best way is probably to create your own rc-script that you will use instead of the "official one".**

Otherwise, your rc-script probably includes an external "config" file if you check it. The include may look like this:

```
. /etc/default/mydaemon-config
```

So that you can edit `/etc/default/mydaemon-config` and do something like:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=whateveryouwant
```

But *be careful*, it may not be what you want, because every process started from the script will have that LD_PRELOAD configuration.

Otherwise, the original script may have something like:

```
DAEMON=/usr/bin/mydaemon
```

So you might be able to change it from `/etc/default/mydaemon-config` with:

```
DAEMON="LDPRELOAD=whateveryouwant $DAEMON"
```

This depends on your original rc-script, that we don't have, so it's only speculation...

Anyway, **these are all workarounds**, and IMHO, you should rather look for a solution to avoid using LD_PRELOAD in the first place.

Comment: Thank your for this detailed answer! The /etc/default/mydaemon-config way works fine for me. Unortunately currently I can't avoid LD_PRELOAD, maybe in the future.