# LD_PRELOAD is not using the correct library

Tags: dynamic-linking

I am trying to override a dynamic link in an executable.

I have an executable "program"

The  command:

```
ldd program
```

outputs:
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6

I have a library a.so:

```
ldd a.so
```

outputs:
libstdc++.so.6 => /mydir/libstdc++.so.6

I tried to override the link in the executable program by doing:

```
setenv LD_PRELOAD a.so
```

now when I run my executable I get:

```
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found
```

why is it trying to read **libstdc++.so.6** from **/lib64/libstdc++.so.6** and not **/mydir/libstdc++.so.6**

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. This doesn't help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106138/automatically-start-an-application-with-a-modifed-ld-preload

Comment: I am using csh, what is the wrong syntax exactly?

Comment: Is "a.so" a path?